# Can't uninstall Edge

Tags: browser, software-uninstall

I have tried using:

```
sudo apt purge microsoft-edge-dev
sudo apt remove microsoft-edge-dev
sudo apt purge microsoft-edge
sudo apt remove microsoft-edge
```

But I get the errors `Package microsoft-edge-dev is not installed, so not removed` and `Unable to locate package microsoft-edge`.

[image]

Edge is still in my favourites bar and opens normally.

Comment: @wha7ever oh god please no...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Depending on what you installed, try:

```
sudo apt purge microsoft-edge-stable
```

or

```
sudo apt purge microsoft-edge-beta
```

or

```
sudo apt purge microsoft-edge-canary
```

Comment: sudo apt purge microsoft-edge-beta worked thanks !
There are so many versions I thought I just couldnt uninstall it.

Answer (score 26):

You can use APT's support for wildcards, uninstalling all versions of Edge you might have:

```
sudo apt purge 'microsoft-edge-*'
```

Comment: This is a more general answer.

Comment: "I say we take off and nuke it from orbit. It's the only way to be sure."

Answer (score 20):

This happens if you mis-spell the package name. Try running

```
apt list --installed | grep edge
```

or

```
apt list --installed | grep microsoft
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Ubuntu 19.10 or newer, or Debian Bullseye or newer, you can check if you have anything installed and named like `microsoft` with:

```
apt list ~i~nmicrosoft
```

Similarly, you can remove (any) with:

```
apt purge ~i~nmicrosoft
```

This uses the new syntax (apt 2.0) that lists:

- `~i`: installed packages
- `~n<pattern>`: packages whose names match the given RegEx pattern (partial match, not full match). We're using `~nmicrosoft` here so any package having `microsoft` in its name gets selected.

For example, on my workstation with Ubuntu 20.04:

```
ubuntu@iBug-Server:~$ apt list ~i~nmicrosoft
Listing... Done
microsoft-edge-stable/stable 96.0.1054.53-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 96.0.1054.43-1]
packages-microsoft-prod/focal,now 1.0-ubuntu20.04.1 all [installed]
ubuntu@iBug-Server:~$
```